# Member function non object

Tags: php, fatal-error

I have made a simple mysqli function wrapper that I use to connect with. When I try to use it, I get a fatal error

```
"Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/cgateams/public_html/home.cga/test.php on line 5"

Line 5: $res = $dblink->query("select * from test");
```

test.php

```
include('includes/db/config.php');

$dblink = db_connect();
$res = $dblink->query("select * from test");
while ($res = $row) {
    echo $row['test'];
}
```

config.php

```
//Database server
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbname';  //sanitized data
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'dbpass';

// db connect to nm database
function db_connect()
{
    global $host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname;

   $dbconnect = new mysqli($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

   if (!dbconnect)
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to CGA database currently');
   else
   return $dbonnect; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a $. It should be:

```
if (!$dbconnect)
```

And then further down in the return value, you've got a typo:

```
return $dbconnect;
```

The error you're getting is because your mysqli object is not being returned (because of the typos).

Also, look at using prepared statements with mysqli - they're very powerful and much more secure than inline queries, especially when you get into passing params.

Comment: Nice catch - I missed the first one.

Comment: Mark: I almost missed the 2nd one :)

Answer (score 3):

In your `db_connect()` function, you are returning `$dbonnect`. It should be `$dbconnect`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a error in config.php: `if (!dbconnect)` → `if (!$dbconnect)`